# Elasticsearch "_cat/indices" api update delayed until search?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-performance

Elasticsearch *(v7.9.2)* got an api `_cat/indices` to show index status, the last change made to `docs.count` seems not visiable, until a search or another update is made.

Is this behaior for the purpose of performance improvement?

And, is there any way to make it always up to date?

---

### @Update - How I obverse this?

I'm using logstash to import data into es.
In the browser I have opened `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`.

After each import, I refresh the browser page, usually it changes.

After the logstash finish, and I terminate it, the count in the page is less than the count from source db (e.g mysql).

Then I refresh the page again and again, it won't change.

But, as I send a query request in `postman` to query the es index, then refresh again, the `docs.count` changed, the total count become the same as in the source db.

**So, I'm summarizing following behavior:**

- At first, the `docs.count` do update after each import *(aka. insert)*.
- But, as importing continues for a while, without querying on the index, the page's `docs.count` stopped updating.
- Then, a query on index will force `docs.count` update to the correct number.
- After that, the above steps will repeat. **It does look like some kind of *delay until necessary* optimization.**

---

And, the **index setting** from `http://localhost:9200/xxx/_settings`:
*(as requested from comment)*:

```
{
  "xxx" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "xxx",
        "creation_date" : "1602844600812",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "default_search" : {
              "type" : "ik_max_word"
            },
            "default" : {
              "type" : "ik_max_word"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "qLFMHhyBQNOOs1u_EcJbBg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7090299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you explain in more details what is happening?

Comment: @Val I've updated the question, please check.

Comment: Can you back your claims with some numbers? How can I reproduce this?

Comment: @Val Please check the `@Update` part in the question.

Comment: Can you share the settings of your index, i.e. what you get from `http://localhost:9200/your-index/_settings` ?

Comment: @Val Added, I didn't do much setting except the `analyzer` and `number_of_replicas`.

Comment: @Val BTW, I'm using `v7.9.2`, might this be a new `feature` (LoL) or performance improvement ?

Comment: @EricWang can you explain your second point ie `If another update is made to the index, then the docs.count is update to reflect the previous update, but not the newest one.` with some example?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja I did more test on a fresh index. and updated the summary part with some correction.

Answer (score 1):

same issue on the ES version v7.9.3

from ES official docs:

> To get an accurate count of Elasticsearch documents, use the cat count
> or count APIs

the cat count API is accurate on my ES cluster.

```
GET _cat/count/log-uwsgi-2021?v
```

| epoch | timestamp | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1638855942 | 05:45:42 | 500 |

Answer (score 0):

last doc.count will be shown when a  [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) occurred.
it will refresh periodic base on [refresh.interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting) setting.

from documention: Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second, but only on indices that have received one search request or more in the last 30 seconds.

Comment: It's not just 1s, if I don't do a query or do further update, the number won't update even after a minute.